# Matrices with entries in $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, operator-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $C^*$-algebra. Consider vector space of matrices of size $n\times n$ whose entries in $\mathcal{A}$. Denote this vector space $M_{n,n}(\mathcal{A})$. We can define involution on $M_{n,n}(\mathcal{A})$ by equality
$$
[a_{ij}]^*=[a_{ji}^*],\qquad\text{where}\quad [a_{ij}]\in M_{n,n}(\mathcal{A}).
$$
Thus we have an involutive algebra $M_{n,n}(\mathcal{A})$. It is well known  that there exist at most one norm on $M_{n,n}(\mathcal{A})$ making it a $C^*$-algebra. This norm does exist. Indeed take universal representation $\pi:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}(H)$ and define linear injective $^*$-homomorphism
$$
\Pi:M_{n,n}(\mathcal{A})\to\mathcal{B}\left(\bigoplus\limits_{k=1}^n H\right):[a_{ij}]\mapsto\left((x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\pi(a_{1j})x_j,\ldots,\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\pi(a_{nj})x_j\right)\right)
$$
Hence we can define norm on $M_{n,n}(\mathcal{A})$ as $\left\Vert[a_{ij}]\right\Vert_{M_{n,n}(\mathcal{A})}=\Vert\Pi([a_{ij}])\Vert$. At first sight this definition depends on the choice of representation, but in fact it does not.

**My question** This norm on $M_{n,n}(\mathcal{A})$ can be defined internally. Namely
$$
\Vert[a_{ij}]\Vert_{M_{n,n}(\mathcal{A})}=\sup\left\Vert\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n x_i a_{ij}y_j^*\right\Vert
$$
where supremum is taken over all tuples $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n\subset\mathcal{A}$,  $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^n\subset\mathcal{A}$ such that  $\left\Vert\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i x_i^*\right\Vert\leq 1$, $\left\Vert\sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_i y_i^*\right\Vert\leq 1$. Is there proof of this fact without usage of structural theorem for $C^*$-algebras, a straightforward proof which can be made by simple checking axioms of $C^*$-algebras?

---

P.S. There is another answer on this question on [mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87224/matrices-with-entries-in-a-c-algebra)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but for further reference this fact is proved (using irreducible representations) as Lemma 2.3 (i) in ["Norming C*-algebras by C*-subalgebras"](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~rsmith/papers/pssnorming_feb29.pdf) by Pop, Sinclair, and Smith.  The norm also has the internal characterization $\|A\|=r(\sqrt{A^*A})$, where $r$ denotes the spectral radius, as for any C*-algebra.

Comment: I think it would be good manners for you to now link to the copy of the question that you have posted on MathOverflow

Comment: In fact, since the question has now been answered on both sites, I suggest that it be closed here.

Comment: @Yemon: Actually, time priority would suggest that the version at MO be closed... annoying that I tend to read MO much more regularly than here (which would have saved some effort between Jonas and I).

Comment: @YemonChoi I don't know the rules of crossposting. So if you insist, I close this question, but this a duplicate of question from another site!

Comment: Actually, I don't think either should be closed.  In many ways, Jonas's answer below is complimentary to mine over at MO, so why not leave them both?

Comment: @MatthewDaws I was worried that people might add later answers, even after Jonas's has been accepted, since this seems to happen occasionally on MSE. Jonas's answer is still visible after closure, isn't it? The point is to avoid duplicated effort, not to penalize anyone.

Comment: @Yemon: I do see the logic.  I don't feel like I know the community views here as I do over at MO, so I think I won't make any further comments...

Comment: @MatthewDaws Well, I guess I don't know the community norms here that well, so I'll let the community decide

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This norm comes from considering $M_n(\mathcal A)$ as acting as operators on the [Hilbert C*-module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_C%2a-module) $\mathcal A^n$, and no Hilbert space representation is required.  I will try to give a fairly minimal overview of the situation in this special case, and more details can be found in the first chapter of Lance's *[Hilbert C*-modules: a toolkit for operator algebraists](http://books.google.com/books?id=90GTut991JcC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)*.  How straightforward it is depends on your familiarity with these objects.  Please feel free to ask for elaboration.

Define on the direct sum $\mathcal A^n$ the $\mathcal A$-valued inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:\mathcal A^n\times\mathcal A^n\to\mathcal A$, given by 
$$\langle (x_i),(y_i)\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^*y_i.$$
The norm on $\mathcal A^n$ is $\|(x_i)\|=\sqrt{\|\langle(x_i),(x_i)\rangle\|}$ (the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for Hilbert C*-modules, Proposition 1.1 on page 3 of Lance, gives one way to see that this is in fact a norm).  Let $\mathcal L(\mathcal A^n)$ denote the set of adjointable operators on $\mathcal A^n$.  These are the maps $T:\mathcal A^n\to\mathcal A^n$ such that there exists a map $T^*:\mathcal A^n\to\mathcal A^n$ satisfying $\langle T(x_i),(y_i)\rangle=\langle(x_i),T^*(y_i)\rangle$ for all $(x_i),(y_i)\in\mathcal A^n$.  With the operator norm, $\mathcal L(\mathcal A^n)$ is a closed subalgebra of the Banach algebra of all bounded operators on the Banach space $\mathcal A^n$, so $\mathcal L(\mathcal A^n)$ is a Banach algebra.  With the conjugate linear involutive anti-automorphism $T\mapsto T^*$, it is also a $*$-algebra.  A straightforward computation shows that $\|T^*T\|=\|T\|^2$ for all $T$, so $\mathcal L(\mathcal A^n)$ is a C*-algebra.

Let $\pi:M_n(\mathcal A)\to\mathcal L(\mathcal A^n)$ be defined by $\pi[a_{ij}](x_i)=\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j\right)$; that is, $\pi$ is the action of $M_n(\mathcal A)$ on $\mathcal A^n$ by multiplying matrices with column vectors.  The fact that $\pi([a_{ij}]^*)=(\pi[a_{ij}])^*$ shows that the codomain of $\pi$ is appropriate.  Since $\pi$ is an injective $*$-homomorphism between $C^*$-algebras, it is isometric (alternatively, this could be used to define the unique C*-norm on $M_n(\mathcal A)$).  (Incidentally, $\pi$ is surjective if and only if $\mathcal A$ is unital.)

Let's see how this gives the characterization in question of the norm.  Let $[a_{ij}]\in M_n(\mathcal A)$.  From the definition of the norm on $\mathcal A^n$ and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for Hilbert C*-modules, 
$$\sup\limits_{\|(x_i)\|,\|(y_i)\|\leq 1}\left\Vert\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n x_i^* a_{ij}y_j\right\Vert=\sup\limits_{\|(x_i)\|,\|(y_i)\|\leq 1}\|\langle (x_i),\pi[a_{ij}](y_i)\rangle\|=\|\pi[a_{ij}]\|=\|[a_{ij}]\|.$$  This is what you have, but with a slightly different appearance due to the convention I used (following Lance) for how the inner product on $\mathcal A^n$ is defined.

Comment: Cf. Matt's answer on MathOverflow

Comment: @Yemon: Thanks.  I saw your comment on the question after I posted, and hadn't seen the MO version before.  Funny, I ended up posting only 1 minute before Matthew, so I can't really blame the unannounced crossposting for the redundancy.