# Block Matrices of Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, adjoint-operators

I'm trying to prove the following: Consider the vector space of matrices of size $n\times n$ whose entries in $\mathcal B(H)$. Denote this vector space by $M_{n,n}(\mathcal{B(H)})$. We can define involution on $M_{n,n}(\mathcal{B(H)})$ by 
$$
T^*=[T_{ij}]^*=[T_{ji}^*],\qquad\text{where}\quad T=[T_{ij}]\in M_{n,n}(\mathcal{B(H)}).
$$
Thus we have an involutive algebra $M_{n,n}(\mathcal{B(H)})$. I want to prove that there exist a norm on $M_{n,n}(\mathcal{B(H)})$ which makes it a $C^*$-algebra. First I try to prove that there exists a $*$ isomorphism between $M_{n,n}(\mathcal{B(H)})$ and $\mathcal{B}\left(\bigoplus\limits_{k=1}^n\mathcal H\right)$. So I define the following map: 
$$J:M_{n,n}(\mathcal{A})\to\mathcal{B}\left(\bigoplus\limits_{k=1}^n H\right):[T_{ij}]\mapsto\left((x_1,.....,x_n)\mapsto\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n(T_{1j})x_j,\ldots,\sum\limits_{j=1}^n(T_{nj})x_j\right)\right)
$$ 
 I proved that this map is $1-1$. My question is : is it onto ? or does it have a closed range? Also , to prove that $J([T_{ij}]^*)= J([T_{ji}^*])=J^*([T_{ij}]))$. I did the following using the definition of the adjoint operator, but I'm not sure where things go wrong: I take $x=(x_1,......,x_n), y=(y_1,.....,y_n)\in \bigoplus\limits_{k=1}^n H $, then 
 $$\begin{align}(J(T)^*x)(y)= x(J(T)y)&= x(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n(T_{1j})y_j,....,\sum\limits_{j=1}^n(T_{nj})y_j)\\& = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left [x_i(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n(T_{1j})y_j,....,\sum\limits_{j=1}^n(T_{nj})y_j)\right] \\&=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (T_{ij}y_j)(x_i)\\&=\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n (y_j)(T^*_{ij}(x_i))
\end{align}$$

Comment: [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104303/matrices-with-entries-in-c-algebra)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem, it is onto. So $M_n(B(H))$ is canonically *-isomorphic to $B(H^n)$. One way to alleviate a little bit the algebra is to introduce the projections 
$$
p_j:H^n\longrightarrow H\qquad(x_i)\longmapsto x_j.
$$
Note that we have
$$
p_i^*:H\longrightarrow H^n\qquad y\longrightarrow (0,\ldots,0,y,0,\ldots,0)
$$
where $y$ is in $i$th position. Then $J:M_n(B(H))\longrightarrow B(H^n)$ is given by
$$
J((T_{ij}))=\sum_{i,j}p_i^*T_{ij}p_j.
$$
It makes it straightforward to check it is a *-homomorphism. And it is not difficult to show that it is invertible with inverse given by
$$
B(H^n)\ni T\longmapsto(p_iTp_j^*)\in M_n(B(H)).
$$
The key things to notice are that $p_jp_i^*=\delta_{ij}\rm{Id}_H$ and $\sum_i p_i^*p_i=\rm{Id}_{H^n}$.

With this *-isomorphism, one can pull back the $C^*$-norm of $B(H^n)$ to make $M_n(B(H))$ a $C^*$-algebra equipped with the norm
$$
\|(T_{ij})\|:=\|J((T_{ij}))\|=\|\sum_{i,j}p_i^*T_{ij}p_j\|.
$$

Comment: @ julien: My question why $T_{ij}^*=T^*_{ji}$?

Comment: @edab12 Why? Nobody said that. Is it when you try to prove $J$ is a * map? This is because we define $(T_{ij})_{i,j}^*:=(T_{ji}^*)_{ij}$ on $M_n(B(H))$. And the $J((T_{ij})^*)=J((T_{ji}^*))=J((T_{ij}))^*$. Essentially because $(p_i^*T_{ij}p_j)^*=p_j^*T_{ij}^*p_i$.

Comment: @edab12 No. That's the way it should be, and it works. For instance, $p_i J((T_{kl}))p_j^*=p_i(\sum p_k^*T_{kl}p_l)p_j^*=T_{ij}$ in view of the Kronecker formula $p_ip_k^*=\delta_{ik}\rm{Id}_H$.

Comment: @edab12 It you're still unsure about all this, I strongly suggest that you write down the $M_2(B(H))$ case in detail. It makes it easier, as you can expand the $4$ coefficients without summation formula.

Comment: I see what do you mean but $$ J(J^{-1}(T))= J((p_iTp^*_j))= \sum_{i,j}p_i^*p_iTp^*_jp_j$$ and $p_ip^*_i\neq Id_{H}$.

Comment: @edab12 True, $pi^*p_j\in B(H^n)$.  All you need is $\sum_ip_i^*p_i=Id_{H^n}$. You should be able to see it.

Comment: ,I just proved it, there was a silly mistake. Thank you very much!

Comment: @edab12 You're, welcome. I'm glad it helped. And I'm happy you asked the question. That's a neat simple algebraic fact, with important consequences. The whole theory of operator spaces, for instance, relies on the structure of $M_n(B(H))$.